# Restore a deleted project from trash

Tags: xcode, macos

I accidentally deleted the complete project from Xcode to trash.
Does anyone know how i can restore the project?

I moved all the files from trash into a new folder and opened the .xcodeproj file. I get a "Framework not found GoogleToolboxFromMac"

Comment: What's the error you are seeing if you restored it completely? Did you keep the same folder structure?

Comment: i get the error "Framework not found GoogleToolboxFromMac"

Comment: Are you able to see `GoogleToolboxFromMac` in your project? How was it integrated?